# How to prevent ion-content resizing while the ionic2 keyboard is open?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I'm using the ionic2 grid system in my application `ion-grid`, the last is resizing once the keyboard is open using on the android platform, any solution to prevent the resizing? I need to push the whole page once the keyboard is open instead of resizing.